# Как работать с github из Windows?

Tags: git, github, windows-10

В общем, через Visual Studio все нормально забирается из репозитория и отправляется назад, но проблема в том, что реализация гита в вижуалке кастрированная, например, я не смог найти то, как работать с сабмодулями из UI...

На помощь приходит консоль, но проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь выполнить:
git submodule update --recursive --depth 1

То, ловлю ошибку прав доступа (репозиторий закрытый).

Что я делаю не так? Может я что-то упустил?

SSH ключи надо сгенерировать или есть какие-то варики другие?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, в логах оказывается еще писалось:

> Host key verification failed.
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Нагуглил похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363553/git-error-host-key-verification-failed-when-connecting-to-remote-repository) и помогло вот

[это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29380765/4244707) решение:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```